# Property does not exist on union type on Phaser with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, phaser-framework

I have been following this tutorial, https://learn.yorkcs.com/2019/02/07/build-a-space-shooter-with-phaser-3-3/ , to make games with Phaser 3 but since I want to deploy them online I'm converting the code to use with TypeScript as I am preparing it via an Ionic 5 app. In the tutorial, I'm supposed to set a player sprite's velocity. For clarity, there are two classes I must create, `Entities.js` (which I created as `entities.ts`) and `Player.js` (which I made into `player.ts`). The entities are supposed to be an extension of `Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite`, and the player is supposed to be an entity, extending the entities class. So far, I get everything working except when reaching the part about setting the player's velocity.

This is my `entities.ts`:

```
class Entity extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
  constructor(scene, x, y, key, type) {
    super(scene, x, y, key);

    this.scene = scene;
    this.scene.add.existing(this);
    this.scene.physics.world.enableBody(this, 0);
    this.setData('type', type);
    this.setData('isDead', false);
  }
}
```

And this is my `player.ts`:

```
class Player extends Entity {
  constructor(scene, x, y, key) {
    super(scene, x, y, key, 'Player');

    this.setData('speed', 200);
    this.play('sprPlayer');
  }

  moveUp() {
    this.body.velocity.y = -this.getData('speed');
  }

  moveDown() {
    this.body.velocity.y = this.getData('speed');
  }

  moveLeft() {
    this.body.velocity.x = -this.getData('speed');
  }

  moveRight() {
    this.body.velocity.x = this.getData('speed');
  }

  update() {
    this.body.setVelocity(0, 0);
  }
}
```

Once I write the line, `this.body.setVelocity(0, 0)`, I get an error: `Property 'setVelocity' does not exist on type 'Body | StaticBody | BodyType'. Property 'setVelocity' does not exist on type 'StaticBody'`. Apparently the body of a sprite can be used for either a `Body`, `StaticBody`, or `BodyType` object. Checking on the documentation, the `Body` class https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html allows for the `setVelocity` function to happen, whereas the `StaticBody` one https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.StaticBody.html doesn't.

Is it that TypeScript expects for each of the possible types to support the function to be used? If so, is there a way for me to specify what type of `body` I'm using? I tried parsing to no avail.

Now, I think there may be a way to specify Ionic I wish to develop in plain JavaScript https://uptoskill.com/ionic-react-javascript/ , but without resorting to that, is there a way to specify which type from the union I wish to use in my function calls? Please let me know, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a self-contained [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), and/or a link to a web IDE that demonstrates the issue.  Right now someone either has to spend time/effort getting this set up in their own environment or else give you an answer they haven't tested themselves.  Good luck!

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this and will comment back with a github repo link

Comment: A GitHub repo isn’t a web IDE, unfortunately. Consider something like codesandbox, the TS Playground, stackblitz, etc. The idea is to reduce the effort needed for someone to reproduce your issue.  Also note that you should make the example *minimal*; pull out everything unrelated to the problem you’re having. Good luck!

Comment: I mean that’d be nice, and I could look that up. But if I can’t find an online tool that runs in the way you describe but for Ionic, then it’ll have to be a repo.

Comment: Sure, and maybe someone will be able to use that to help you, but I for one could not commit to installing a repo in my own environment to answer a SO question.  Your question is tagged with ionic-framework so maybe someone already has this environment set up and has insight about it.  Still, I suspect this has less to do with ionic and more to do with discriminating union types in TypeScript... and that you could reproduce your issue with *toy* versions of the classes/types in question, without requiring anything other than pure TypeScript.

Comment: Btw, you could use Stackblitz to create a demo project... If you want you can fork this Ionic 5 demo as a starter: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64790924

Comment: @jcalz I created a demo. Please check it out https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD2ATAntA3gKGtAbgUxHmAEsAXZALmgDsBXAWwCM8AnaAXmgAYBuLafhDykAagSJlkAChxU6TVgEp0-bKQAWxCADp8hEuQ64e2fgF8MFjKEgwAyqTCliwBChVWbUaHYAOLMjwVbEYkSjgw6AAfH0dnV0jOAHIkvisQYWhSPAhSPwDso2o8AHcff0CpRT4MbNz8wO1QlG0hUXEDaQBWaqA

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/qNBrbN) solve your problem then?  If a `Sprite`'s `body` really might not be a `Body` then you have to test it before you call `setVelocity()` (otherwise you run the risk of doing `undefined.setVelocity()` at runtime).  If that suffices I'll write it up; otherwise please elaborate.   Also, you should put the [mcve] code and link into the question text itself (you can edit the question) rather than just a comment.

Comment: @jcalz Yes it worked. Would you write this down as an answer so I can give you credit for it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by jcalz, the answer was to test if the object in question is an instance of the class that contains the function to call. In other words, to ensure that we wish to use `Body` and not `StaticBody`. This could have been done by simply checking if the function exists in the object:

```
if('setVelocity' in this.body) {
  this.body.setVelocity(0, 0);
}
```

More specifically, we could check if the object is an instance of the object expected, via:

```
if(this.body instanceof Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body) {
  this.body.setVelocity(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message indicates that your player body is one of these types `'Body | StaticBody | BodyType'` but StaticBody does not have a `setVelocity` method. Typescript has the concept of [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) to handle this situtation, where you work with union types that have different members.

The solution here, is to check if the this.body has a setVolicity function.

```
update() {
    // when true typescript know it is not a StaticBody
    if ("setVelocity" in this.body)
    this.body.setVelocity(0, 0);
  }
```

You could also define a custom typeguard function and use it inside the if statement like this:

```
//custom typeguard function with the return type 'body is Body'    
function isBody(body: Body | StaticBody): body is Body {
  return (body as Body).setVelocity !== undefined;
}

if (isBody(this.body)) {
  this.body.setVelocity(5); 
}
```

Comment: although I see how the solution makes sense, it doesn't seem to work. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD2ATAntA3gKGtAbgUxHmAEsAXZALmgDsBXAWwCM8AnaAXmgAYBuDLaBDykAagSJlkAChxU6TVgEp0A7KQAWxCADp8hEuQ64+2AL4Zz0DKEgwAyqTCliwBChXnr4KNDsAHFjI8FWxGJEo4cOgAH19HZ1cozgByZL5PEGFoUjwIUn9AnKNqPAB3XwCgqUU+DGIAM2gpHLyCoO0wlG0hUXEDZGVMNVz8ypyO8O7hMX1JKQBWGqtTIA

Comment: unfortunately my first example with a property accessor typeguard seems not to work. I´v updated the anwser wich iliustrate the in operator and custom typeguard functions.